# A hard inequality indian olympiad problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials, muirhead-inequality

If $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers, prove that:
$\left(x+y+z\right)^2\left(yz+xz+xy\right)^2\le 3\left(y^2 + yz + z^2\right)\left(x^2 + xz + z^2\right)\left(x^2 + xy + y^2\right)$.

I have been stuck in it. It is an Indian Olympiad problem. Can you guys help me out, please?

Comment: Which olympiad, can you specify please.

Comment: I am not sure but it's either rmo or inmo

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @Aditya Saran It's interesting that your inequality is true for all real variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that:

$$x^2+xy+y^2=\frac{3}{4}(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2\geq \frac{3}{4}(x+y)^2$$

Therefore

$$(x^2+xy+y^2)(y^2+yz+z^2)(z^2+zx+x^2)\geq \frac{27}{64}(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2$$

And it remains to prove

$$9(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\geq 8(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$$

We can prove this with AM-GM:

$$8(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)=8(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)+8xyz \leq 9(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$$

Answer (score 7):

Let $p = x+y+z, \ q = xy+yz+zx, \ r = xyz$. 
Rewrite the inequality as
$p^2 q^2 \le 3(p^2q^2 - q^3 - p^3 r)$.
Since $q^2 \ge 3pr$, it suffices to prove that
$$p^2 q^2 \le 3(p^2q^2 - q^3 - p^3 \frac{q^2}{3p})$$
or
$$q^2(p^2-3q)\ge 0.$$
It is obvious. We are done.

Comment: Surprisingly elegant.

Comment: Why q^2 is greater than 3pr

Comment: @Aditya Saran  $q^2-3pr = (xy)^2+(yz)^2+(zx)^2 - xy\cdot yz - yz\cdot zx - zx\cdot xy \ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\quad3\left(y^2 + yz + z^2\right)\left(x^2 + xz + z^2\right)\left(x^2 + xy + y^2\right)-\left(x+y+z\right)^2\left(yz+xz+xy\right)^2\\=\sum_{sym} \left(2x^4y^2z^0+0.5x^3y^3z^0+0.5x^4y^1z^1-2x^3y^2z^1-x^2y^2z^2\right)\\=2\sum_{sym} \left(x^4y^2z^0-x^3y^2z^1\right)+0.5\sum_{sym} \left(x^3y^3z^0-x^2y^2z^2\right)+0.5\sum_{sym} \left(x^4y^1z^1-x^2y^2z^2\right)$

By [Muirhead's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality), $\left(4,2,0\right)\succ\left(3,2,1\right),\left(3,3,0\right)\succ\left(2,2,2\right),\left(4,1,1\right)\succ\left(2,2,2\right)$

$\because$ The expression $\ge 0$, equality holds when $x=y=z$

$\therefore 3\left(y^2 + yz + z^2\right)\left(x^2 + xz + z^2\right)\left(x^2 + xy + y^2\right)\ge\left(x+y+z\right)^2\left(yz+xz+xy\right)^2$

($\succ$ denotes [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization))

Comment: Is there any simple method??

Comment: It may have some elegant ways, but this way can prove almost all inequality

Comment: I think muriheads inequality is difficult for high school students.

Comment: It is actually not that difficult, it just needs to spend some time for expanding.

Comment: Is it accepted in Olympiads to write it directly without proving it.

Comment: Have you used am GM inequality

Comment: i haven't used it, but it is acceptable